# How to pass the parameter from react native webview to external javascript files function which is stored in xcode

Tags: react-native

How to pass the params from react native webview to external javascript function,

I have app.js file which is added in my react native project, and it contain some function like callfromapp(data), and i need to pass the parameter from react native webview to app.js function.

iam adding function injectJSFileFromWeb() inside webview.js iam giving the app.js file path but when it calls app.js file, iam getting error like document is not defined,

inside react native webview.js,

```
   <WebView 
                ref={ref => (this.webview = ref)}
                source={{ uri: 'example/index.html' }} 
                originWhitelist={["*"]}  
                domStorageEnabled={true}
                startInLoadingState={true}
                allowFileAccess={true}
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
                 onLoad={()=>injectJSFileFromWeb()}
               />

  injectJSFileFromWeb() {
        //give the filename according to your need
        var jsFileName = require('../../../ios/build/../example/app');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WebView has attribute `onMessage`, which can receive messages from `WebView`. See example in official API documentation https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md#the-windowreactnativewebviewpostmessage-method-and-onmessage-prop